# How to check if a value was entered, and if it wasn't-do not insert it into db?

Tags: php, mysql

**Form1.php**

```
<?php
if(isset(".$_POST[fname].", ".$_POST[lname].", ".$_POST[mail]."))
{$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (fname, lname, mail) VALUES ('".$_POST[fname]."', '".$_POST[lname]."', '".$_POST[mail]."')"; 
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());}
else{
    echo "No Values To Insert";
}
?>
```

I'm trying to check if the value was set, and if it wasn't-throw an error without inserting into DB.

Help?

Comment: It'll be tough with a blank PHP page

Comment: True, very true-corrected it:)

Comment: why don't you just check in PHP before executing the `INSERT` command Do `echo $_POST['mail']` and see what the value is set to when you check (and don't check) the mail checkbox.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Is it not rejecting when it should?

Comment: [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) is used to check for existence... I do not think that it will do what you think it will here.

Comment: @Duthcie432-Not sure I understand-how do I check it?

Comment: why do you call `isset` with strings like that? it's best to use `isset($_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['mail'])`

Comment: @elusive actually, `isset` returns `FALSE` for `NULL` values too

Comment: Ok I tried it: if(isset($_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['mail']))
{$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (fname, lname, mail) VALUES ('".$_POST[fname]."', '".$_POST[lname]."', '".$_POST[mail]."')"; 
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());}
else
{
    echo "No Values To Insert";
}

Comment: No Go...B.T.W-if I want to insert code tage inside a comment, how do i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
if ( isset ($_POST['fname']{0}) and isset( $_POST['lname']{0}) and isset( $_POST['mail']{0}) ){
   // Insert into db
}
else{
   echo "Please fill all the feilds";
}
```

What happens here is even if the user didnt enter any value into the fname feild, still the $_POST['fname'] will be set. So the isset ($_POST['fname']) will always return true if the form was submitted.

But when you check for isset ($_POST['fname']{0}) you are making sure that atleast one charater is entered and the feild is not empty. you can also use an is_empty but this is much better way.

Also The catch in using this is "{}" are going to be removed in php version 6. so if you are planning to upgrade your servers in the future then this might cause a small problem. But using "[]" instead of "{}" will solve that problem in php version 6.

Comment: why not use `isset` in combination with `empty`? `isset(...) && !empty(..)`?

Comment: because if u give false or 0  as fname then also empty($_POST['fname']) will return true. In this case it might be ok, but in general case its not advisable.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, i read the heading of the question and mis-understood. What you have for code should work for catching failed inserts (though I recommend breaking off a test against the mysql_error instead of an or die(...)`. But, you can do an insert based on if the value already exists in the database by using [this page as a reference](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/25/insert-if-not-exists-queries-in-mysql/)